# Updating objects parameters using python creates multiple objects

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, bmesh, mathematics

I can update a text curve object when I change the frame and it doesn't create multiple objects but how can I do the same with a mesh object.

Code:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

font_curve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT",name="Font Curve")
font_curve.body = 'Current Frame: ' + str(scene.frame_current)
font_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Font Object", font_curve)
scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj)
  
def recalculate_obj(scene):
    font_curve.body = 'Current Frame: ' + str(scene.frame_current)         
     
def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(recalculate_obj)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(recalculate_obj)

register()
```

[image: Frame animation]

It doesn't create multiple Font objects (**this is what I want it just replaces the last one**)

[image: Font]

But when I try and do it with a mesh object I run into problems due to the **"_add"**

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

font_curve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT",name="Font Curve")
font_curve.body = 'Current Frame: ' + str(scene.frame_current)
font_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Font Object", font_curve)
scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj)

cyl_obj = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius = 1) 

def recalculate_obj(scene):
    font_curve.body = 'Current Frame: ' + str(scene.frame_current) 
    cyl_obj = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius = scene.frame_current)
          
def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(recalculate_obj)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(recalculate_obj)

register()
```

[image: Mesh]

[image: mesh multi]

My goal is to replace the line **bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add** command with the python line below but have the **a**, **b**, **c** and **d** variables in the **x_eq, y_eq, z_eq** animated with out creating multiple objects.

```
cyl_obj = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_xyz_function_surface(x_eq = "a+v", y_eq = "b*sin(2*pi*u+c)", z_eq = "cos(2*pi*u)/d")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swap out the mesh**

[image]

Just like the font change handler is swapping out the body of the font, *ie* the data part of the text object, can do same with meshes.

Proof of concept

Use the create surface operator to create an object stepping along v changing the steps and the point to step to, max.

After each call, save the mesh, remove the object.

**Script to create the meshes via operator**

```
import bpy
from addon_utils import enable
from math import pi

from bpy import context

enable("add_mesh_extra_objects") # make sure addon is enabled

# default 4pi in 128 steps
step_value = pi / 32
steps = 10
for step in range(1, 129, steps):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_xyz_function_surface(
        range_v_max=step * step_value,
        range_v_step=step,
        )
    me = context.object.data
    me.name = f"XXXX{step}"
    me.use_fake_user = True
    bpy.data.objects.remove(context.object)
```

After running this script have a number of "XXXX" meshes

```
>>> D.meshes['XXXX
                  1']
                  101']
                  11']
                  111']
                  121']
                  21']
                  31']
                  41']
                  51']
                  61']
                  71']
                  81']
                  91']
```

Now simply a case of writing a handler to use these.

**Handler to swap in the meshes created**

```
import bpy

def swap_ob_mesh(ob_name, mesh_base_name):
    
    def handler(scene, depsgraph):
        ob = scene.objects.get(ob_name)
        f = scene.frame_current
        me = bpy.data.meshes.get(f"{mesh_base_name}{f}")
        if ob and me:
            ob.data = me
            
    return handler

# while testing
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
        
# test call

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(
        swap_ob_mesh("Cube", "XXXX")
        )
```

Notes: IMO never mix context and handlers. When it comes to render most likely wont work.

Consider shape keys.  If instead simply ran the operator only changing v max (not steps) if all the meshes produced have the same number of verts / edges / faces simply join them as shapes and animate the shape key.

To demonstrate the "stepping" nature of swapping the mesh have used 10 frame steps.  Reducing this to 1 will be as smooth as it gets.

On a side note this is a "proof of concept" scrubbing the timeline may produce unexpected results since the mesh is only swapped when exists.

Comment: I hear you. if not done "correctly" and you mix context and handlers incorrectly when scrubbing with the timeline it `will cause the memory to increase every time you scub the time line` (and the `memory usage will NOT go down`) also some other strange things happen when switching between edit mode and object mode.  I found some useful python code and connected it to Animation Nodes and will post it as a workaround / one of the correct ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is by just using Python. (**Don't use this way, unless you have to.  This will increase your memory usage every-time you scrub the time-line and the memory WILL NOT GO DOWN!!!)**

**Notice the memory usage!:**
[image: Memory usage]

Python code to run:

```
import bpy
import math

def my_handler(scene):
    # Deselect all
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # Select the object
    if bpy.data.objects.get("Hyperboloid") is not None:
        bpy.data.objects['Hyperboloid'].select_set(True)

    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    
    # mesh arrays
    verts = []
    faces = []

    # mesh variables
    numX = 50
    numY = 50
    
    # get frame value
    frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current

    # fill verts array
    for i in range (0, numX):
        for j in range(0,numY):
            # nomalize range
            u = 8*(i/numX-1/2)
            v = 2*math.pi*(j/(numY-1)-1/2)

            x = 2*math.sqrt(1+u*u)*math.cos(v)*(frame/12)
            y = 2*math.sqrt(1+u*u)*math.sin(v)*(frame/12)
            z = 12*u/(frame/12+0.01)

            vert = (x,y,z)
            verts.append(vert)

    # fill faces array
    count = 0
    for i in range (0, numY *(numX-1)):
        if count < numY-1:
            A = i
            B = i+1
            C = (i+numY)+1
            D = (i+numY)
            face = (A,B,C,D)
            faces.append(face)
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = 0

    # create mesh and object
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Hyperboloid")
    object = bpy.data.objects.new("Hyperboloid",mesh)

    # set mesh location
    object.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)

    # create mesh from python data
    mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces)
    mesh.update(calc_edges=True)

    # assign a material to the newly created curve
    mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")
    object.data.materials.append(mat)
    
    # active smooth shading to object
    bpy.data.objects['Hyperboloid'].select_set(True)    
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Add the handler to handlers
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid mixing context and handlers together as @batFINGER mentioned a workaround is below.

Combine some Python code with the Animation Nodes plugin.

[image: Animation nodes node]

**Python Code Used in eq_2:**

```
import bpy
import math

def parametricfunc(val1):

    # mesh arrays
    verts = []
    faces = []

    # mesh variables
    numX = 50
    numY = 50
       
    # fill verts array
    for i in range (0, numX):
        for j in range(0,numY):
            # nomalize range
            u = 8*(i/numX-1/2)
            v = 2*math.pi*(j/(numY-1)-1/2)

            x = 2*math.sqrt(1+u*u)*math.cos(v)*(val1/12)
            y = 2*math.sqrt(1+u*u)*math.sin(v)*(val1/12)
            z = 12*u/(val1/12+0.01)

            vert = (x,y,z)
            verts.append(vert)
            

    count = 0
    for i in range (0, numY *(numX-1)):
        if count < numY-1:
            A = i
            B = i+1
            C = (i+numY)+1
            D = (i+numY)
            face = (A,B,C,D)
            faces.append(face)
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = 0
            
        
        edges = AN.algorithms.mesh_generation.grid.quadEdges(numX, numY)
        polys = AN.algorithms.mesh_generation.grid.quadPolygons(numX, numY)
    return x, y, z, verts, A, B, C, D, faces, edges, polys
            
x, y, z, verts, A, B, C, D, faces, edges, polys  = parametricfunc(val1)
```