# Animate Mesh Vertices via coordinate values from calculation

Tags: animation

## Mesh vertex animation

**My prerequisites:** Little to no experience with blender, advanced experience in python

**Starting Point:** Mesh *M* with *n* vertices and *m* faces as *.obj* file.

**Next step :** Change coordinates of the *n* vertices incrementally.

**What I have :** Python script that calculates the new vertex coordinates for *X* timesteps

**What I need :** How to apply the list of new vertex coordinates to the mesh in blender with the related timesteps (=frames). (Python API of blender?) Is there something like:

```
for timestep in range(0,len(timesteps)):
    newCoordinates = calculateCoordinates(mesh.vertices, timestep)
    mesh.co = newCoordinates
    mesh.Update()
    
    # --> add keyframe to animation
```

**What I tried:**

- [PlugIn Animall](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/is-it-possible-to-animate-a-meshs-geometry-without-using-shape-keys) seems to have that functionality, however, I was not able to get that to work for my problem
- [Keyframe animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/how-to-keyframe-mesh-vertices-in-python) is an older post from 2015. The aim appears to be similar, however none of the code snippets is working nor is leading to the desired results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keyframe mesh vertices in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/how-to-keyframe-mesh-vertices-in-python)

Comment: Have made the necessary (_and very minor_)  edits to 2 of 3 answers to update them to 2.8.  The other handler technique is similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187361/updating-objects-parameters-using-python-creates-multiple-objects

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74063/animating-z-surface-math-functions

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! Will check that tonight

Comment: Thank you very much batfinger, it works now! Just one little additional question : Is it possible to "vectorize" the "for v in mesh.vertices"- loop in your first suggested answer? I do have N - matrices containing the vertex coordinates for N frames. I would just have to rewrite the vertice coordinates for each frame instead of for each vertex for each frame. Is it possible to improve its performance here?

Comment: Related    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190165/quick-keyframe-frame-insertion-for-shape-keys-with-foreach-set-from-data/190227#190227   instead of animating the verts with keyframes make a shapekey for each.  Example of using numpy for setting vert coords https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/180184/15543  (for a curve couldn't find a link for object quickly).. anyway same, ravel the numpy array.